# hashtable keys from multiple objects in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Hashtable mainhash = new Hashtable();

```
        testdata td = new testdata() { value = "td" };
        td.hash.Add("1", "tdvalue1");
        td.hash.Add("2", "tdvalue2");
        td.hash.Add("3", "tdvalue3");
        td.hash.Add("4", "tdvalue4");
        td.hash.Add("5", "tdvalue5");

        testdata td1 = new testdata() { value = "td1" };
        td1.hash.Add("1", "td1value1");
        td1.hash.Add("2", "td1value2");
        td1.hash.Add("3", "td1value3");
        td1.hash.Add("4", "td1value4");
        td1.hash.Add("5", "td1value5");

        testdata td2 = new testdata() { value = "td2" };
        td2.hash.Add("1", "td2value1");
        td2.hash.Add("2", "td2value2");
        td2.hash.Add("3", "td2value3");
        td2.hash.Add("4", "td2value4");
        td2.hash.Add("5", "td2value5");

        testdata td3 = new testdata() { value = "td3" };
        td3.hash.Add("1", "td3value1");
        td3.hash.Add("2", "td3value2");
        td3.hash.Add("3", "td3value3");
        td3.hash.Add("4", "td3value4");
        td3.hash.Add("5", "td3value5");

        testdata td4 = new testdata() { value = "td4" };
        td4.hash.Add("1", "td4value1");
        td4.hash.Add("2", "td4value2");
        td4.hash.Add("3", "td4value3");
        td4.hash.Add("4", "td4value4");
        td4.hash.Add("5", "td4value5");

        mainhash.Add(1, td);
        mainhash.Add(2, td1);
        mainhash.Add(3, td2);
        mainhash.Add(4, td3);
        mainhash.Add(5, td4);
```

how to select all the keys using SelectMany by Linq into one list??
 what i need to do in this??

```
var values = mainhash.Values.Cast<testdata>().Select(x => x.hash)
                                             .SelectMany(x=> x.Keys);
```

what is wrong in this??

Comment: random question: why not use `Dictionary<,>` instead of `Hashtable` - that'll save an awful lot of `Cast<>` etc. Now: what happens currently when you compile / run this?

Comment: it give this error 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't know the type to use from `Hashtable.Keys`.

Try:

```
var values = mainhash.Values.Cast<testdata>().Select(x => x.hash)
                           .SelectMany(x => x.Keys.Cast<string>());
```

But better: use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` instead of `Hashtable`.

Comment: thank you marc, but Dictionary<TKey,TValue> instead of hashtable??

Comment: He meant Dictionary<String, String> as your testdata.hash's datatype. Read up on generics.

Comment: @debashishgiri since you are using LINQ, generics is definitely available; much more convenient (and less prone to accidental bugs) than the non-generic APIs such as Hashtable. It would also reduce the code here to: `var values = mainhash.Values.SelectMany(x => x.hash.Keys);`

Answer (score 0):

try below query -

```
var values = mainhash.Values.Cast<testdata>().SelectMany(x => x.hash.Keys.Cast<string>());
```

But, use dictionary instead of hashtable. It actually reduce the overhead of casting the objects.

hope above code helps you !!